# Intermitted line & pictured not in the box

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, circuitikz

I wanna make an intermitted line to illustrate the long length of a line. something like this:

[image]

I'm using circuitikz this is the code so far there is a problem here that it is not inside the box.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside, titlepage, openbib]{article}

    \usepackage{tikz}
        %Tikz is een library die toestaat om tekeningen te maken
        \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
            %Shapes
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
            %Arrows
        \usetikzlibrary{calc}
            %Calculation
        \usetikzlibrary{decorations}
            %Decorations
        \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
            %Backgrounds
        \usetikzlibrary{fit}
            %
        \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
            %
        \usetikzlibrary{chains}
            %
    \usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors]{circuitikz}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
        %http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf
        \tcbuselibrary{listings}
        \tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\begin{document}

%---Image--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
\begin{figure*}[ht!] %het blokschema
    \centering
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.2cm, auto]
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
                (1,3) node[spdt,xscale=1, yscale=1,anchor=in] (myspdt1) {}
                (4,3) node[spdt,xscale=-1,yscale=1,anchor=in] (myspdt2) {}
                (8,0)   node[ground, yscale=1]{}
                        to[full led]        (8,3)
                        to(myspdt2.in)
                (0,0)   node[ground]{}
                        to[vsourcesin]      (0,3)
                        to(myspdt1.in)
                (0,2) node[right]{$V_{s}(t)$}
                (myspdt1.out 1) -- (myspdt2.out 1)
                (myspdt1.out 2) -- (myspdt2.out 2);
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tcolorbox}   
        \caption{Het eerste probleem} 
        \label{fig:Het eerste probleem} 
\end{figure*}
%---Image--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Edited it, adding what you requested

Comment: Isn't this basically the same issue like in your other question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370002/tikzpicture-outside-of-my-box/370029#370029